# How to change order of package compilation in OpenWRT AA?

Tags: openwrt, buildroot

I have some custom packages added to OpenWRT AA which is depending on busybox. It is observed that OpenWRT AA builds my custom packages before making base-file packages. So busybox is not available during my custom package build and my image build fails. Is there a way to configure the order of package build in OpenWRT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenWRT uses alphabetical order for compiling extra package for e.g., if your package is part of base-files, capital letter (start letter of your package name) will be compiled first and then the small letters packages in alphabetical order. If you want some other package to be compiled before your package then you can add DEPENDS:= to your custom package metadata.